# C# - Cannot tag a random number with a statement

Tags: c#, random

So i'm working on a revision tool that'll ask defined questions randomly using console command C#. I can create the random number but cannot seem to use the Switch function properly. Can anyone help?

```
           // The random Object
        Random Number = new Random();

         while (true)
        {
            int Question = Number.Next(1);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", Question);
            string Answer = Console.ReadLine();

            if (Answer.ToLower() == "finished")
            {
                break;
            }

            if(Answer.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Write Please");
                continue;
            }

            switch (Question)
            {
                case 0:
                    {
                            Console.WriteLine("What is the nucleus of an atom made of");
                            if (Answer == "neutrons and protons")
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Well Done!");
                            }
                            if (Answer == "protons and neutrons")
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Well Done!");
                            }
                             Console.WriteLine("Try Again");
                        break;
                    }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You do know that `int Question = Number.Next(1);` will always result in `Question == 0`?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is quite strange; for example you are trying to read a response before you have even printed a question.  However, your immediate question relating to the random number is simple.

You are using `int Question = Number.Next(1);`.  According to [MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1bc8e5(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns a non-negative random integer that is less than the specified maximum.

since you are storing the number as an int, and you have 1 as the specified maximum, you will *always* receive `0` from this assignment.  I would assume that you have other case statements in your switch, and if you use the number of questions you have rather than `1`, your switch will work.  You will still have other issues with things printing in the wrong order, though....